# Understanding akka hello-world example

Tags: java, akka

I'm learning `Akka` and now I'm trying to understand their basic [**Hello-world example**](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/hello-akka-java8#code/src/main/java/HelloAkka.java) (fragment):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TimeoutException {
    // Create the 'helloakka' actor system
    final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("helloakka");

    // Create the 'greeter' actor
    final ActorRef greeter = system.actorOf(Props.create(Greeter.class), "greeter");

    // Create the "actor-in-a-box"
    final Inbox inbox = Inbox.create(system);

    // Tell the 'greeter' to change its 'greeting' message
    greeter.tell(new WhoToGreet("akka"), ActorRef.noSender());  //1 <------- Here

    // Ask the 'greeter for the latest 'greeting'
    // Reply should go to the "actor-in-a-box"
    inbox.send(greeter, new Greet());

    // Wait 5 seconds for the reply with the 'greeting' message
    Greeting greeting1 = (Greeting) inbox.receive(Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    System.out.println("Greeting: " + greeting1.message);  //2 <-------- Here

    // Change the greeting and ask for it again
    greeter.tell(new WhoToGreet("typesafe"), ActorRef.noSender());  //3 <--- Here
    inbox.send(greeter, new Greet());  
    Greeting greeting2 = (Greeting) inbox.receive(
                          Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));  //4 <-------------- Here
    System.out.println("Greeting: " + greeting2.message);

    //...
}
```

What's going on up here?

I. At `//1` the actor `greeter` fire-and-forget the message `WhoToGreet("akka")` to no-sender. So **no one** will recieve it. But for some unclear reason, at `//2` we receive it (`greeting1`) from the actor `inbox`. Why? How did the message wind up with `inbox`? We did not send it to `inbox`. It's kind of miracle...

II. At `//3` is happening pretty much the same. We tell to noSender and then recievin it from the `inbox`...

Answer (score 2):

This is the line which tells the inbox to consume greetings given to the `greeter` actor:

```
// Ask the 'greeter for the latest 'greeting'
// Reply should go to the "actor-in-a-box"
inbox.send(greeter, new Greet());
```

It is called before using `inbox.receive` to acknowledge and retrieve the message now placed in the inbox. Although the message's target does not exist in the actor system, the actor system *itself* is taking the message.

`ActorRef.noSender()` appears to mean that the greetings have not come from a different actor; when the actor sends the message forward, this is likely to change into a unique ActorRef for the actor sending it (so you can trace the message to the previous actor).

Comment: Ah, if we call `actorRef.tell(msg, anotherActorRef)` means that an actor referenced to by `anotherActorRef` sends `msg` to `actorRef`, right?

Answer (score 0):

In these lines:

```
greeter.tell(new WhoToGreet("akka"), ActorRef.noSender());  //1 <------- Here
```

the "greeter" object is being sent the message -- a new "WhoToGreet" object -- with no specified sender. Greeter will receive the message.

What "noSender" means is if the greeter responds to the message, the response will not be delivered -- it will likely end up with the dead letter actor.